# What is the reason behind invoking base class's constructor while defining DBContext in EF? Is there any other way of doing it?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

For example if I have a class as 'MyContext', I am supposed to invoke the DbContext's constructor by passing the connectionString to it. Can anyone tell me why is it invoked this way. I mean, is there any other way we derive the DbContext class without passing the connectionstring explicitly.

```
class MyContext: DbContext
{

     public MyContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
     {

     }
}
```

Comment: So EF knows what connection string to use obviously, it can't magically know it ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several constructor overloads for `DbContext`

`DbContext` is not abstract so you can in fact create a `DbContext` instance without deriving/inheriting from it. **In such case you need a connection string** or similar information. [See the full overload list here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbContext)

But when you are deriving from `DbContext` you can in fact create a parameterless constructor for your `MyContext` class and not even call the `base` constructor if you will. The default `DbContext` constructor is protected, so it will get called if you don't specify a `base` overload

In fact, I've seen and used code like this:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public static Func<string> ConnectionStringProvider = () => "TheNameOfTheConnectionString";        

    public MyDbContext() : base(ConnectionStringProvider())

    //....
}
```

Where the `ConnectionStringProvider` delegate is replaced in Unit/Integration tests, because it's a static field (I'm not encouraging the practice, but I've seen it)

For example:

```
MyDbContext.ConnectionStringProvider = () => "MyTestConnectionStringName";

using (var ctx = new MyDbContext())
{
    // This code will use conn string named MyTestConnectionStringName
}
```

But I guess 99% of the time, as Alexander said, you just want to call the base constructor with the connection string, such that EF knows this information beforehand and you don't have to worry about it anymore